# Unable to get property X of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net

After upgrading an asp.net web forms application from the 2.0 framework to the 4.0 framework it appears references like the following are broken in javascript

```
document.RF_Login.hidSubmit.value="Yes";
```

It results in the following error:

[image: javascript error]

Why does this occur when upgrading to the 4.0 framework?  Is there something I can do to not have to update all references like this in the entire website?

### EDIT

The name of the page is RF_Login.aspx and inside the page the following exists:

```
<FORM id="RF_Login" method="post" runat="server">
```

Comment: You might want to check what `RF_Login` is, where it's from and why it's `undefined`.

Comment: Is 'RF_Login' the ID or the name of the form in your app? Also, are you sure your Javascript is executing after the document is fully composed in the browser?

Comment: I've edited my post.  Nothing was changed really between the upgrade so I'm not sure why the `RF_Login` object is undefined.

Comment: Also if i reference `RF_Login` via `document.forms.RF_Login` it is defined.  `.forms` is the important part

Comment: 1. Did you upgrade from Visual Studio or did you just upgrade the application pool from v2.0 to v4.0?
2. What is the ID of the form when you view the source of the page?

Comment: The upgrade was done in visual studio.

Comment: Would it be a problem to just change it to `document.getElementById('RF_Login')`?

Comment: I can do this yes but I was looking for a method where I wouldn't have to change every reference in every web page as there are 100's of pages containing references similar to this.

Comment: Have the generated ID's changed after the upgrade from v2 to v4? i.e. when you view the page source?

Comment: @Seany84 I'm not sure exactly what IDs or html you are referring to exactly.

Comment: The ID's of your ASPX controls (i.e. the ones with `runat=server`).
When they are rendered as HTML. Right-click on your page and view the source. Search for `<form` and tell me what the ID is.

Comment: It's pretty much the same as I posted in the edit: `<form method="post" action="RF_Login.aspx" id="RF_Login">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is due to .NET 2.0 using AutoID for the .NET control ID generation. Whereas, .NET 4.0+ uses the predictable clientId mode.

As taken from: [.NET Framework 4 Migration Issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee941656(v=vs.100).aspx)

> The new clientIDMode setting in ASP.NET 4 lets you specify how ASP.NET
> generates the id attribute for HTML elements. In previous versions of
> ASP.NET, the default behavior was equivalent to the AutoID setting of
> clientIDMode. The default setting is now Predictable.

Resolution:

> To disable the new client ID mode, add the following setting to the
> Web.config file:
>
> `<pages clientIDMode="AutoID" />`
>
> or
>
> `<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" />`
>
> Or both combined:
>
> `<pages clientIDMode="AutoID" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" />`

Comment: Great stuff, I knew I came across this one a few years back.